# Stripping HTML code from an item in an array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a Javascript array which contains items of string values. However, some of these items contain text in between `HTML` tags. Below is an example of my array.

`var myArr = ["Weather", "very", "<span style="font-weight:bold;">nice</span>"]`

How could I strip the `<span></span>` tags from the array leaving just the word `nice`?

I have looked into using jquery's .match() to detect if the array contains HTML, but I've no success when testing it in JSFiddle.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: That's not a valid array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## UPDATED

An updated version that prevents against XSS attacks making use of [`$.parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/).

```
myArr = $.map(myArr, function(str, i){
  return $("<div/>").append($.parseHTML(str)).text();
});
```

---

**PREVIOUS UPDATE**

Probably you can try something along these lines:

```
myArr = $.map(myArr, function(str, i){
  return $("<div/>").html(str).text();
});
```

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/GTyZe/)

Comment: Guess you should use `$.map` instead of grep.

Comment: I was almost sure there was no `$.map` since `Array#map` is not yet a viable option. But, agree

Comment: There is. `=]` [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) does exactly what you wanted, while [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) merely returns a filtered version of the original array. That means, grep evaluates the return value to true/false and then keeps or removes the item from the return value based on that.

Comment: Yeah, was just writing up so other readers that are lazy to follow the doc links would see. `:P` BTW There's a small XSS problem with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/GTyZe/1/ I'd recommend [`$.parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) with the `keepScripts` param set to `false`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, nice catch. It's true that not all readers may not prevent themselves against something like that

Comment: Yup, perfect answer. Of course if you are not applying this function to arbitrary user input, the old version is fine. Though future users that search for "strip tags" will often use it on user input so better be on the safe side. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: `$.parseHTML` is still vulnerable to XSS if the tag contain JavaScript in onerror/etc. attribute. An example is shown in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArr = [];
var myArr = ["Weather", "very", "<span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">nice</span>"]
$.each(myArr, function(index, value) {
  newArr.push($('<div/>').html(value).text());
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YS9TP/).